# Puppeteer not loading page - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Here is a simple program on puppeteer:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    async function run() {
       const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            
            args:[ `--proxy-server=104.233.50.38:3199`]
        });
        ;
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.authenticate({
                username: 'myusername',
                password: 'mypassword'
            })
            await page.goto('https://google.com')
    };

run();
```

**Note: I have tried similar with over 10 proxies and none of them are working in puppeteer**

The credentials are exactly what is provided to me, I have checked multiple times.

This is what I get:

[image: Puppeteer not loading page]

Now again , this is the console of the page:

[image: Puppeteer error loading page console view]

**Why is this happening?**

I checked the addresses and username, password multiple times. There is no other error message except this.

Comment: is this username and password for your proxy server? or is there a captive portal you need to authenticate to?

Comment: Yes it is for my proxy server

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3253 and https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use puppeteer-page-proxy, it offers username and password auth very easily. It also supports http, https, socks4 and socks5 proxies. https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy

You can define the proxy this way:

```
const proxy = 'http://login:pass@IP:Port';
```

or

```
const proxy = 'socks5://IP:Port';
```

Then you can use it per request:

```
const useProxy = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', req => {
    useProxy(req, proxy);
});
```

Comment: Should I put this ```page.setRequestInterception(true)``` after ```browser.newPage()```?

Comment: this is a per request conf, if you need the proxy only for specific page, you can just use await useProxy(page, proxy);

Answer (score 2):

It seems that page.authenticate is not working for me either,instead you can use page.setExtraHTTPHeaders

```js
async function run() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, 
    args: ['--proxy-server=104.233.50.38:3199']
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders
({'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('username:password').toString('base64'),
});
};
 
run();
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I replace the ```username:password``` with my credentials and run the program it gives an ```Error: net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT ```.

Comment: Above is working for puppeteer version 1.18.0 , but failing and giving below error for version 2.1.1 Error: net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/3611052c055897e5ebbc5b73ea295092e0c20141/services/network/public/cpp/header_util_unittest.cc#L75

What verison you are using?